# How to check NAND type used in a SSD in Ubuntu

Tags: ssd

I was wondering if there exists some application that can show which NAND type is used in a SSD - MLC,SLC,TLC...

Is it possible?

Comment: I think you have to search for that kind of data via the manufacturer's web site.

Comment: Of course, however, sometimes they are not inclined to disclose that type of info.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've not come across that type of data, at least not with most tools I've used on Ubuntu  - `lshw`, `dmidecode`, `udev`, `udisksctl` and so on; so I think it's not possible,no yet at least.

What's possible is to display whether a drive is [rotational or not](https://askubuntu.com/a/792937/295286), where no rotational information implies an SSD; more importantly, you can find out vendor or SSD model via same commands, and take that to search engine to find detailed specs on the drive.

SSDs typically should have a microcontroller that takes care of reporting the relevant information to the host machine. So in theory there should be a way to check whether that controller exposes such information or not. There's high probability they don't expose that information, simply because no OS usually cares about that. This also means that we can't really find such information , at least not yet, with Ubuntu tools.